# regex for extracting hash tags without spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using this:

```
$t = "#hashtag #goodhash_tag united states #l33t this";
$queryVariable = "";
if(preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $t, $arrHashTags) > 0){
    array_filter($arrHashTags);
    array_unique($arrHashTags);
    $count = count($arrHashTags[2]);
    if($count > 1){
        $counter = 1;
        foreach ($arrHashTags[2] as $strHashTag) {
            if (preg_match('/#\d*[a-z_]+/i', $strHashTag)) {
                if($counter == $count){
                    $queryVariable .= $strHashTag;              
                } else{
                    $queryVariable .= $strHashTag." and ";
                }
                $newTest = str_replace($arrHashTags[2],"", $t);                 
            }
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        }
    }
}
echo $queryVariable."<br>"; // this is list of tags
echo $newTest;   // this is the remaining text
```

The output based on the `$t` above is:

```
#hashtag and #goodhash_tag and #l33t
united states this
```

First problem:

if `$t = '#hashtag#goodhash_tag united states #l33t this';` i.e without space between two tags, the output becomes:

```
#hashtag and #l33t
#goodhash_tag united states this
```

Second problem:

if `$t = '#hashtag #goodhash_tag united states #l33t this #123';` i.e with an invalid tag `#123` it somehow disturbs my list of tags extracted in `$queryVariable` like the output becomes

```
#hashtag and #goodhash_tag and #l33t and // note the extra 'and'
united states this
```

Please help on these two if anyone?

Comment: i would really appreciate if anyone could help somehow in addition to upvoting the question :)

Comment: A little suggestion would be to use `(#[A-z_]\w+)` instead. =)

Comment: @DreamEater do you mean, at the line where `preg_match` is being used and do you want me to replace the whole pattern or a part of it?

Comment: I meant it here: `if(preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $t, $arrHashTags) > 0){`

Comment: this solves the second problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using so many comparisions etc. for your regex. You can simply have the following:

```
$t = "#hashtag #goodhash_tag united states #l33t this #123#tte#anothertag sth";
$queryVariable = "";
preg_match_all('/(#[A-z_]\w+)/', $t, $arrHashTags);
print_r( $arrHashTags[1] );
```

---

To get them as string with `and` joining them, you can use implode.

```
$queryVariable = implode( $arrHashTags[1], " and " );
```

For the remaining text, you can have `preg_replace` or `str_replace`(whichever you are comfortable with).

---

Here is the [codepad link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qTYhUX).

Comment: Although your answer seems to achieve all my needs, thanks for that. i have one question though, are you sure what all comparisons i was doing would be taken care of by this code that you suggested?

Comment: @coder101 Except for the `array_unique` part, yeah. You can add that function too.

Comment: also what do you think about `array_filter`, to filter out any null values?

Comment: There won't be any `NULL` results. @coder101 Think about it `:P`.

Comment: :) yeah, i know. just that i am too paranoid about any errors, so thought of including as many fail-safe measures as possible/

Comment: I'd suggest a reading of [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) on Optimization(premature :P) @coder101

Comment: and hey, i just included the array_unique and it gives an error. could you please check at this [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pKxfiR)

Comment: the opening lines of the article pretty much says it all. :) thanks and please check the link that i provided

Comment: I just checked, if i use just `array_unique($arrHashTags[1])` instead of `$arrHashTags[1] = array_unique($arrHashTags[1]);` after the preg_match_all, it repeats the tag. why so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26607/discussion-between-dream-eater-and-coder101)